# use of laravel route() helper function inside the web.php file

Tags: laravel

I'm new to  laravel and stackoverflow and I am  trying to  use the route helper  in order to  reuse the url  of named route to  create a new route. how to  do  such  thing?

```
Route::get('/user/{id}/profile', function (string $id) {
    // ...
})->name('profile');

$url = route('profile', ['id' => 1, 'photos' => 'yes']);
```

I have tried to run this test  code and it shows an error: `the route  is not defined`

I run it inside the `web.php` file.

Comment: You can't. What are you trying to accomplish that you think you need to use this helper function within your route definitions?

Answer (score 0):

Route files (All files inside `routes` folder) and config files are loaded but not parsed. That's why that route doesn't exists untill Service provider is dispatched.

You can use `url()` helper instead.

Or show us why do you need to use `route()` helper inside `web.php` file and hope we give you great workaround of doing that.

Comment: Route::get('/', [ProductController::class, 'home']);
$route=Route::get('/soldes', [ProductController::class, 'soldes'])->name('soldes');
Route::get('/femmes', [ProductController::class, 'women'])->name('femmes');
Route::get('/hommes', [ProductController::class, 'men'])->name('hommes');

Route::get('{previous_page?}/details/{id}', [ProductController::class, 'details'])->name('details');

i want to  force the previous page route parameter to be one the url above

Comment: Here is not used `route()` helper

Comment: Route::get('/soldes', [ProductController::class, 'soldes'])->name('soldes');

Route::get('/femmes', [ProductController::class, 'women'])->name('femmes');

Route::get('/hommes', [ProductController::class, 'men'])->name('hommes');

Route::get('{previous_page}/details/{id}', [ProductController::class, 'details'])->whereIn('previous_page', [route('femmes'), route('hommes')])->name('details');

this is what i want to  do  but it don't work  and I understand base on your previous response that I can't use the route helper so how to  do  that?

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do. do you want to save previous page in url?

Comment: i want to  generate a route base on the previous page only if this page is the hommes or femmes route the {pevious_page} parameter should be a path that is the URI  from  the route name femme or  from  hommes

Comment: You definitely shouldn't put that bussiness logic inside `web.php` or any other static files. No logic will work when routes are cached.

Comment: how should i do it ?